# ubuntu suspend shuts down all apps

Tags: 20.04, suspend, hibernate

I am new to ubuntu and have been trying to use suspend feature like windows sleep. But when restart pc after suspend all apps are shutdown. It's like the pc was shut down not suspended. I have searched extensively for a solution to this but cannot find any resource. Any help would be appreciated.

I am new to ubuntu and have been trying to use suspend feature like windows sleep. But when restart pc after suspend all apps are shutdown. It's like the pc was shut down not suspended. I have searched extensively for a solution to this but cannot find any resource. Any help would be appreciated.

`sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` output:

```
Mar 24 08:48:38 pc-desktop systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 24 08:48:38 pc-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 24 08:48:38 pc-desktop systemd-sleep[14804]: Suspending system...
~
~
~
lines 1021-1043/1043 (END)
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1616575715.1403] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1616575715.1405] device (enp0s31f6): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop whoopsie[1825]: [08:48:35] offline
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop dbus-daemon[940]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=943>
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop dbus-daemon[940]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1616575715.1582] device (enp0s31f6): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop avahi-daemon[934]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d97c:8320:4a0:ceba on enp0s31f6.
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop avahi-daemon[934]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s31f6.IPv6 with address fe80::d97c:8320:4a0:ceba.
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop avahi-daemon[934]: Interface enp0s31f6.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1616575715.1836] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1616575715.1836] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): state changed bound -> done
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop avahi-daemon[934]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.10 on enp0s31f6.
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop avahi-daemon[934]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s31f6.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.10.
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop avahi-daemon[934]: Interface enp0s31f6.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1616575715.1890] device (enp0s31f6): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop nm-dispatcher[14761]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Mar 24 08:48:35 pc-desktop kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: NIC Link is Down
Mar 24 08:48:36 pc-desktop gnome-shell[2101]: [2094:2125:0324/084836.690526:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Mar 24 08:48:38 pc-desktop systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 24 08:48:38 pc-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 24 08:48:38 pc-desktop systemd-sleep[14804]: Suspending system...
```

`free - g` output

```
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             62           3          57           0           1          58
Swap:             1           0           1
```

I have a dual OS setup with windows on one ssd and linux on another.

Comment: In a terminal window, the command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs (where it shutdown instead of suspending). How much RAM and swap do you have? The `free` command will show you. Read `man journalctl  free is-supported`.

Comment: @waltinator thanks for reply, I've added the output of both of those commands to original post

Comment: AFAIK, Ubuntu suspends by writing the system state and all the tasks to swap space. You have very little swap space and a lot of memory.

Comment: Also note that on some hardware Windows offers suspend but Linux does not. Do some research to see how others are are managing with your hardware.